# The spring way to handle repository methods

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to figure out the Spring way of doing things as I'm new to the platform. I have a repository declared as follow:

```
public interface ScreenshotRepository extends JpaRepository<Screenshot, UUID>
```

I have a few query methods in there, but now I want to have another method that is not just a query. The method runs a query and if a record is found, it returns it, if not, it creates it with some default parameters. Where should this method go?

I saw [custom repository implementations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) on the documentation, but because they are separate from the actual `JpaRepository` they don't seem to have access to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this the spring way you can create a service and Autowire your repository in that service and create your custom function in your service while using your repository to execute your queries

```
@Service
public class ScreenshotService{
    @Autowired
    private ScreenshotRepository screenshotRepository;


    public Boolean customMethod(){
        screenshotRepository.sampleQuery()
        //blah blah...
    }
.
.
.
```